# Why I can't upload cookies to Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies

I save cookies like this:

```py
auth_func()

# if successful auth
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Then I try to use them on the same domain:

```py
cookies = pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb'))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

But I get the error:

> File "test.py", line 115, in 
>       user_agent = auth()   File "test.py", line 50, in auth
>       driver.add_cookie(cookie)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 894, in add_cookie
>       self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
>   argument: invalid 'expiry'   (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.44)

Cookies structure:

```py
>>> cookies = pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl', 'rb'))
>>> for c in cookies:
...     c
...
{'domain': '.linkedin.com', 'expiry': 1633780372, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '***********', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': '*************'}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that cookies, for some reason, are written with the wrong name. Solved it like this:

```py
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cookies:
    if cookie.get('expiry', None) is not None:
        cookie['expires'] = cookie.pop('expiry')
pickle.dump(cookies, open('cookies.pkl', 'wb'))
```